# Unable to "Start Debugging" a VS2017 VSIX project

Tags: vsix, vs-extensibility

I am using VS 2017 (15.2)...

For unknown reasons I am no longer able to debug my VSIX projects... If I "Start Debugging" the experimental instance comes but then it immediately goes away, and the debugging session ends... If however I "Start Without Debugging" the experimental instance comes up fine... It's only when debugging that the problem occurs... In order to isolate the problem I created a new VSIX project and sure enough it exhibits the same problem... This behavior I described is what usually happens but on occasion the experimental instance will not even launch... Instead I get an error message that looks something like this:

[image]

This was all working not too long ago... Anyone have any ideas on what the issue could be??? How to fix??? A workaround??? BTW one of my colleagues found this link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/14382/vs2017-rc-crash-when-debugging-vsix.html... Unfortunately though the fix provided did not work... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When my VS experimental instances end up in an unstable state (which happens often when updating my extensions without uninstalling previous incompatible versions). I use a shortcut that is created when installing VS.

The shortcut with name "Reset the Visual Studio 2017 Experimental Instance" has the following target:

```
%comspec% /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Tools\Bin\CreateExpInstance.exe" /Reset /VSInstance=15.0_10c5512a /RootSuffix=Exp && PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

in the Debug-Settings I have added the line

```
/rootsuffix Exp
```

as Command line arguments in the Startup options.